# Xcode 8 beta 4: "Could not attach to pid : 1110" when running on physical device

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10, xcode8-beta4

I made a messages extension and when I run it on the iOS simulator everything runs no problem. When I try to run it on my phone, it compiles and says running for about 5 seconds before crashing and giving me a pop down message in Xcode saying `Could not attach to pid` Here is a screenshot:

[image: The error I am getting]

I am using Xcode 8 beta 4 with iOS 10. Everything runs fine in simulator this is on physical device. I have rebooted and restarted everything. I have even tried on two phones. Anyone know the solution?

Thanks

Comment: This is the second time I've seen someone call Xcode 8.0 beta _x_ "Xcode 8.x beta".

Comment: @tktsubota my mistake -- fixed

Comment: I have the same error occurring, with Xcode 8.0 GM, but on the simulator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay this is a tough one. I went searching though the Xcode beta 4 release notes and found the answer in the known bugs section:

[image]

Comment: Thx you save my day.