# iMessage sticker app error message pid:2336

Tags: xcode, ios10, imessage, xcode8-beta6

I am trying to build an iMessage sticker application. Following along with the template I run into the same issue each time where the app will appear to run, but then I receive the following error message and my stickers are not attached to the stickers running on my decvice.

[image]

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to Attach to Process ID Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535844/failed-to-attach-to-process-id-xcode)

Comment: I had the same issue and followed this advice. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38811979

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue running on device. Try this is solved my problem.

On the device, go to Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management, tap on the profile name that authorized this app, and tap Trust.

Hope this helps