# Testing iOS Message Sticker app on a real device

Tags: ios, ios10, imessage

I'm building a iOS 10 Sticker App, and it works great on the simulators, but I was hoping to also test it out on few devices. When I try to run the app on an iPhone running iOS 10, it only shows me the icon, and not all the stickers associated with the app. Is it not possible to test a Sticker app on a real device due to it being in Beta?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 beta 4: "Could not attach to pid : 1110" when running on physical device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811591/xcode-8-beta-4-could-not-attach-to-pid-1110-when-running-on-physical-device)

Comment: What Fabio said, this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Was unable to attach from xCode to device so I tried doing it through testflight and the stickers show up on device that way.